# Difference between Array and ArrayCollection(Flex)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

What's the difference between array and arraycollection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the ArrayCollection is designed for the Flex framework. It acts like a `Proxy` for a given  `Array` instance. This means it can listen for modifications made to the source `Array` and update it self when this happens. It also contains a subset of additional methods required specifically by the framework (have a look at the [IList](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/collections/IList.html) implementation for instance).

Answer (score 1):

One important difference is that `ArrayCollection` raises events whenever it is modified.  This allows you to do data binding on it more effectively than you could do on an `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

An ArrayCollection is a wrapper for an Array that lets it be used by GUI elements. Iterating through them is a bit tricky however, see here: http://npcomplete.weebly.com/1/post/2009/10/for-loops-in-actionscript.html